# Can blob versions be retained while moving or renaming?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am using the latest .NET SDK for Azure Storage and enabled versions in Blob storage. I can upload, list all versions of blobs using my C# code. I would like to maintain the versions in case of a move or rename. Is it possible to do such a thing automatically? If not, is there any workaround that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using the docs. Here are the snippets of my code that worked:

```
var files = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.Metadata, BlobStates.Version, prefix: prefix);
foreach (BlobItem file in files)
{
      var versionFile = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(file.Path).WithVersion(file.versionId);
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string newFileName = file.Name.Split("/").Last();
                    string newPath = $"{destFolderPath}/{newFileName}";
                    
                    BlobClient newFile = rootDir.GetBlobClient(newPath);
                    await newFile.StartCopyFromUriAsync(file.Uri);
                    fileCount++;
                    if (file == files.Last())
                    {
                        var rootFile = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(file.Path);
                        rootFile.DeleteIfExists();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Removed some of the project specific code here so anyone looking to use this, please initialize appropriate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Azure blob supports [blob versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview) natively, you can enable it by following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-enable?tabs=portal).

You can also maintain old blob versions by [creating Blob snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/snapshots-overview).
If you are using .NET SDK, [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/snapshots-manage-dotnet?tabs=dotnet) could be helpful.

Comment: Yes, these versions aren't being retained when I move or rename the blobs. That is where I need some solution. Thanks!

Comment: @SVG, I think creating Blob snapshots manually could meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that option. Will update here how it goes.