# Using C# Azure Storage Libraries, is it possible to delete previous versions of a blob using an ETag?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am building a file management tool with Azure functions, Azure Blob storage and a react front end. I can display details about blobs and its previous versions. I have access to the versiondId and the ETag of the current version and previous versions.

I was thinking it might be a good feature to allow users to remove previous versions of blobs. If there are 100s of previous versions, and the files are large, then a large cost could be incurred for storing previous versions.

I have enabled soft-delete and versioning on the storage account.

The code snippet below works great for deleting the current version using the ETag match condition. If I swap the ETag for a valid previous version though, the deletion does not succeed.

```
// Get a reference to a container where the blob is located
BlobContainerClient containerClient = _blobService.GetBlobContainerClient(deleteMessage!.ContainerName);

Dictionary<string, bool> deletedItemStatus = [];

// Get a reference to the blob you want to delete
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(deleteMessage.Path);

foreach(var eTag in deleteMessage.ETags)
{
    // TODO - this works perfectly well if we delete the current version using its ETag - but we cant delete previous versions...
    deletedItemStatus.Add(eTag, await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, new BlobRequestConditions { IfMatch = new ETag(eTag) }, cancellationToken: token));
}

var deletedOK = deletedItemStatus.All(r => r.Value == true);

_logger.LogInformation("File Delete Operation completed successfully? : {Status}", deletedOK);

return deletedOK;
```

Instead of success I get:

```
[2024-02-19T15:35:44.696Z] Status: 412 (The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.)
[2024-02-19T15:35:44.699Z]
[2024-02-19T15:35:44.701Z] ErrorCode: ConditionNotMet
[2024-02-19T15:35:44.702Z] Headers:
[2024-02-19T15:35:44.703Z]
[2024-02-19T15:35:44.704Z] Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

I know the ETag is good because I just received it prior to this call, and it works if I swap it to the ETag of the current version.

I am not getting anywhere fast with this. Does anyone have any ideas? Beginning to think its not supported, but CoPilot seems to think it is, but the code examples dont work!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66249706/2325216

Comment: It did! The thing I missed was the .WithVersion chained method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help in the comments from Andrew B, I found this code works:

```
foreach(var version in deleteMessage.Versions)
{
   // Get a reference to the blob you want to delete
   BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(deleteMessage.Path).WithVersion(version.Value);
   deletedItemStatus.Add(version.Key, await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(cancellationToken: token));
}
```

Versions are a Dictionary<string, string> I defined. The Key happens to be the ETag, and the Value is the versionId. I am not using the ETag at the moment, but I believe they should come as unique ETag/Version pairs, so it seems reasonable to use the ETag as the key.

The missing bit was the "WithVersion" method. I also had to remove optional parameters from the delete operation.

Answer (score 2):

> If I swap the ETag for a valid previous version though, the deletion
> does not succeed.

The error message is correct. You are getting this error because you are doing a conditional delete on the base blob and the ETag that you are using does not match with the current tag.

---

To delete a blob version, you will need to use the version id of that blob. You cannot delete a blob version just by using ETag. ETag can be used as an additional condition though i.e. delete a blob version only if the ETag matches.